# Библиотека парсер логических выражений из строки

Tags: php

Есть ли какая-то библиотека в open source, которая вычисляет логическое выражение из строки?
Например, из строки "1 === 1" вернуть true.

PHP

Comment: [`eval()`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.eval.php) называется

Comment: в eval можно засунуть что угодно. Для него надо обертку писать. Об этом и вопрос: есть ли готовое решение или самому писать

Comment: Один вопрос: зачем?

Comment: И ещё вопросы: а для каких типов это должно быть по-вашему? И почему именно для них (или только для них)

Comment: вы же свой вопрос предельно кратко изложили, не потрудившись деталей добавить. такой и ответ. если в вашем логическом выражении только числа и операторы, то вся обертка сократится до простейшей регулярки. Если нет, то, наверное, следует это в вопросе указать, вам так не кажется?